# Text-shadow rendering on Android 4.4.2 bug

Tags: android, css, webkit, android-4.4-kitkat

we develop and android app that opens a full screen browser and loads some content. this all works fine excepted this little bug:

only under 4.4.2 (works fine on 10 devices with 4.2, and also tested on 4.4/5) only the text-shadow css feature drops the shadow on the top of the text box instead of behind the text. it fails in our app, also fails in the default browser, but works fine in Chrome or firefox on the same android stick.

as you can see it from the attached screenshot the box shadow works fine.

also this issue is related to kernel 3.0.36+ and works fine on (Nexus7 4.4.2 with) 3.4.

so as we think this will be an issue with the webkit engine, and looking for some solution/workaround

[image]