# Text-shadow move to top of container in Android Native Browser 4.4.2

Tags: android, html, css, android-browser

I design a web page with some text-shadow, in all browser works well but in Android Native Browser all text-shadow move to top of container.

For example: i have a text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #FFF and when i open in Android Browser i need to set it ike 2px 52px 2px #FFF for it take its correct position.

Thanks for help :D

Answer (score 0):

Use @media for andriod browser

example andriod( 320px to 480px width)

**CSS**

```
  /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
  /* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

  /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

  /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

  /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, i know i can use media-querys for it but i want to know why my shadow render so bad. It's very anormal. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28109017/text-shadow-rendering-on-android-4-4-2-bug it's like this issue

Comment: @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
   h1{2px 52px 2px #FFF}
}